# XML -Markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed

Tags: xml, dtd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE  hotels  SYSTEM "food.dtd">
<breakfast_menu>
 <food>
  <name>Turfle waffles</name>
  <price>$5.95</price>
  <description>This two turfle which has 2 famous product  is with real choco and maple 
   syrup</description>
  <calories>650</calories>
 </food>

 <food>
  <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
  <price>$24.6</price>
  <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
  <calories>900</calories>
 </food>

 <food>
  <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
  <price>$4.78</price>
  <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped 
   cream</description>
  <calories>400</calories>
 </food>

 <food>
  <name>Fried Toast</name>
  <price>$7.68</price>
  <description>Thick slices made from our homemade wheat dough bread</description>
  <calories>250</calories>
 </food>

 <food>
  <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
  <price>$7.95</price>
  <description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and England popular  hash browns</description>
  <calories>1500</calories>
 </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

I tried the following code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!ELEMENT breakfast_menu (food+)>
    <!ELEMENT food (name, price, description, calories)>
    <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT calories (#PCDATA)>
    <breakfast_menu>
     <element>
      <name>Turfle waffles</name>
      <price>$5.95</price>
      <description>This two turfle which has 2 famous product  is with real choco and maple 
       syrup</description>
      <calories>650</calories>
     </element>
    
     <element>
      <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
      <price>$24.6</price>
      <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
      <calories>900</calories>
     </element>
    
     <element>
      <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
      <price>$4.78</price>
      <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped 
       cream</description>
      <calories>400</calories>
     </element>
    
     <element>
      <name>Fried Toast</name>
      <price>$7.68</price>
      <description>Thick slices made from our homemade wheat dough bread</description>
      <calories>250</calories>
     </element>
    
     <element>
      <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
      <price>$7.95</price>
      <description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and England popular  hash browns</description>
      <calories>1500</calories>
     </element>
    </breakfast_menu>
```

This code is throwing an error:
Fatal error:
Public ID: null
System ID: file:/home/p10936/food.dtd
Line number: 8
Column number: 2
Message: The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.
Fatal

I need to convert the XML code into the DTD Code.
I am new to this! And I cannot find any help!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the XML declaration (first line) and the content ie. everything starting from `<breakfast_menu>` till the of the file from `food.dtd`. DTD files are supposed to *only* contain markup declarations.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Yes, now I understood the difference!